# Тормоза при работе с сетью

Tags: android, сеть

Есть приложение-заготовка, которое работает с API Яндекс переводчика.

Проблема: при получении запросов и попытке положить результат в TextView в приложении могут возникать микротормоза, особенно при медленном соединении.

Весь его код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mEditText;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                try {
                    mTextView.setText(new AsyncRequestToGetTranslatedText().execute(s.toString()).get());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    private class AsyncRequestToGetTranslatedText extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            try {
                String sURL = String.format("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?" +
                        "key=%s" +
                        "&text=%s" +
                        "&lang=%s-%s", "ключ апи тут", arg[0], "ru", "en");
                URL url = new URL(sURL);
                HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                request.connect();
                JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                JsonElement root = jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
                JsonObject jsonObject = root.getAsJsonObject();
                return jsonObject.get("text").getAsString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как можно оптимизировать код?

Comment: Выполнять запросы в отдельном потоке. Почитайте про паттерн MVC.

Comment: @Leonid этот код -- упрощённый пример. Расскажите подробнее, как в Android правильно работать с потоками и какие изменения стоит внести конкретно в этот пример.

Comment: Вы в методе слушателя onTextChanged() выполняете длительный по времени метод execute. И так как отрисовка GUI происходит в этом же потоке - GUI зависает. Чтобы это исправить необходимо вынести метод execute в отдельный поток и создавать поток там же. Потом принимать результат и выводить. GUI будет работать, поток будет ждать ответа на запрос. Поизучайте Java multithreading для понимания.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете `AsyncTask` - вызывать `get()` на нём - против логики и цели создания этого класса. Этот класс должен зупуститься, выполнить работу в фоновом потоке и вернуть результат в основной поток. Вы же методом `get` заставляете основной поток ждать когда выполнится запрос. На совсм медленном соединении у вас приложение упадёт по `ANR` после 5с.

Вам надо использовать метод `onPostExecute()` класса `AsyncTask` - в него придёт результат работы с сетью и в нём уже и надо назначать текст в `TextView`. Вот правильный код, который не будет тормозить основной поток:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mEditText;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                new AsyncRequestToGetTranslatedText().execute(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    private class AsyncRequestToGetTranslatedText extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            try {
                String sURL = String.format("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?" +
                        "key=%s" +
                        "&text=%s" +
                        "&lang=%s-%s", "ключ апи тут", arg[0], "ru", "en");
                URL url = new URL(sURL);
                HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                request.connect();
                JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                JsonElement root = jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
                JsonObject jsonObject = root.getAsJsonObject();
                return jsonObject.get("text").getAsString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "";
            }
        }

        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mTextView.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```